# How do I get the div value with ajax/jquery in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript

I am using CI_Calendar custom template, I'm trying to get it so when a user clicks on the {content} a href "div class = test" on the calendar an alert will pop up with that shows what was in the div class="day_num". Ex: Monday the 1st has a link that says 'Test' on it, when I click on that link "Test' an alert will popup and say 1. As of now the alert box keeps saying undefined.

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').click(function() {
      test= $(this).find('.test').html();
      alert(test);
    });
  }); < /script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your mark up, the `day_num` element is actually a sibling and not a child.

The easiest way would just be to traverse backwards 1 using [jQuery's .prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

```
day_num = $(this).prev('.day_num').html();
```